# Tell Tika not to parse XML

Tags: java, apache-tika, tika-server

I would like to configure a Tika server that does not parse XML files.

I wrote the following config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<properties>
  <parsers>
    <parser class="org.apache.tika.parser.EmptyParser">
    </parser>
  </parsers>
</properties>
```

This configuration tells Tika to parse absolutely nothing. In particular, it should not parse XML files. Furthermore, it should fail at extracting any document because the supported types of EmptyParser is the empty set. Let verify that by starting a Tika server:

```
java -jar tika-1.17-src/tika-1.17/tika-server/target/tika-server-1.17.jar --config tika_config.xml
```

and submit a simple XML file (a copy of tika_config.xml):

```
curl -T samples/sample.xml http://localhost:9998/meta --header "Accept: application/json"
```

and we get:

```
{"Content-Encoding":"ISO-8859-1","Content-Type":"application/xml","X-Parsed-By":"org.apache.tika.parser.html.HtmlParser","language":""}%
```

Why did Tika parse that XML files? Moreover, why did it use HtmlParser instead of an XML parser?

This preferential treatment seems to be specific to XML, as I could not reproduce it with plain/text, application/pdf, application/zip, application/octet-stream and not even text/html! However I could not find any hint of what's happening.

Comment: There seems to be a bug / unexpected side effect. I've raised https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TIKA-2551 for it

Comment: Thanks! You basically answered my question.